# Authentication with SmartCard sending a SOAPUI request

Tags: certificate, soapui, keystore, smartcard

I have always forwarded requests over SOAPUI using certificates in the KeyStore configured in SOAPUI's SSL settings. Now I need to use a certificate saved in a smartcard. I have my nice smartcard reader that works fine in all other contexts.

Is there a way to configure SOAPUI to use the smartcard certificate?